# Issue connecting to the SQL server from Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, connection-string

I have the below Controller that gets the account as the input parameter, which connects to the Sql server and will have to call the stored procedure passing account.The stored procedure inserts a new record if the Account is not present and updates it when already in there

```
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
       SqlConnection DbConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
       DbConnection.Open();
       SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[usp_InserUpadte]", DbConnection);
       command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       //create type table
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       table.Columns.Add("AccountID", typeof(string));
       table.Rows.Add(Account);

       SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_TT", table);
       parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
       parameter.TypeName = "Account_TT";
```

Below is the ConnectionString in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="DBConnection"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The stored procedure is like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InserUpadte] 
@account_TT AS account_TT READONLY

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

 MERGE dbo.[Account] prj
 USING @account_TT tt
 ON prj.AccountID = tt.AccountID
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET prj.CounterSeq = prj.CounterSeq+1
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (AccountID,CounterSeq)
 VALUES (tt.AccountID, 1);

 COMMIT TRANSACTION;

 END;
```

where the table type is created with

```
CREATE TYPE account_TT AS TABLE
(
 AccountID     nvarchar(50),
 )
 GO
```

When I try to call the API it doesnot throw any exception but neither creates/update any records with the stored procedure. I tried to debug the adding breakpoints. I see the in

```
DbConnection.Open();
```

[image]
Looks like the connection is not opened. I am able to connect to the SQL server from the same server I am working on though SQL Management Studio. Can anyone please suggest me what could be the issue.

Comment: SQL server 12.0.4436.0

Comment: Could you include the code where you actually execute your `command ` ?

Comment: Are you asking about the API call?

Comment: It seems you are passing a table as a parameter to store procedure. Are you sure that you have created the custom table type for it?

Comment: Yes I will add them in thequestion

Comment: if your remove ;MultipleActiveResultSets=True in your connetionstring?

Comment: are you closing the connection before you run the command?

Comment: @Esperento57 I tried to remove `;MultipleActiveResultSets=True` still getting `"Invalid operation. The connection is closed."`

Comment: @ADyson I am not calling in my code `DbConnection.close()`

Comment: the connection object could be going out of scope though. Show us where you actually run the command that causes the error.

Comment: I call the API from the browser with the input parameter like http://hostname/api/controllername?Account=IT. And tried to run them in the debugging mode

Comment: Your `SqlCommand command` must be executed at some point

Comment: I see the SqlCommand command executed I see the Connection is Open, But now the issue is it is not updating/inserting , I see the account "IT" is passed as a parameter to stored procedure but still not update/insert. Can you please help me with this

Comment: Thanks for all your input. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't connect to data base correct. try this:

```
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection) { CommandTimeout = 160, CommandType = commandType })
        using (var dataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

            connection.Open();
            dataAdaptor.Fill(dS);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have open connection.Correct way of opening connection

```
string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;

using(SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon))
    {
      if (dbConnection.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
      {                      
          con.Open();   
      }
    }
```